# Как вывести результат foreach php отдельным переменным?

Tags: php

Как можно вывести результат foreach php отдельным переменным?
Написал так:

```
$datebem = $datebe[1];

switch($datebem){
    case '01':
    echo 'январь';
    break;
    case '02':
    echo 'февраль';
    break;
}
```

`echo $datebem;` выведет 02, вместо желаемой 'февраль'. Как правильно написать, чтобы можно было отдельным переменным использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ниже функция преобразования месяца.

```
function rus_month($var) {
    $month = array(
        '01' => 'январь',
        '02' => 'февраль',
        '03' => 'март',
        '04' => 'апрель',
        '05' => 'май',
        '06' => 'июнь',
        '07' => 'июль',
        '08' => 'август',
        '09' => 'сентябрь',
        '10' => 'октябрь',
        '11' => 'ноябрь',
        '12' => 'декабрь'
    );

    return $month[$var];
}
```

Обращение:

```
echo rus_month($datebem);
```

**P.S.** Данная функция решает вашу задачу. Пользуйтесь.